# inputAccessoryView event handler for interactively scrolling the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I am building a chat application and I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView`. I have a custom view that contains an autoexpanding `UITextView` and used it to override the `inputAccessoryView` in my view controller. The tableview has `keyboardDismissMode` as `interactive`. When I am trying to drag the keyboard up/down, I want to get the event so I can either update my tableview's bottom constraint or update my tableview's content inset. The notifications for `keyboardWillShowNotification` nad `keyboardWillHideNotification` only gives me the notification when the keyboard has finished showing and hiding. I need something that can notify me while the user is dragging the keyboard up/down. Just like how WhatsApp have in their chat screen.